# Encontrar o índice de dataRow

Tags: c#, winforms, datatable

Estou percorrendo um `DataTable` com um `foreach` utilizando uma variável do tipo `DataRow`, porém estou precisando recuperar o índice do `DataRow` que estou percorrendo.

```
foreach(DataRow row in DataTable.Rows)
{
     string descricao = Convert.ToString(row["id"] +" - "+ row["nome"]);
     int index = ??;
     int value = Convert.ToInt32(row["id"]);
     checkedListBoxControl1.Items.Add(value);
     checkedListBoxControl1.Items[index].Description = descricao;
}
```

Comment: A resposta atendeu o que você queria? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Comment: sim, desculpa havia esquecido de aceitar a resposta;

Comment: Tranquilo, só queria saber se faltava algo =D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É possível usar o método [**`IndexOf()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/zd89w8cx(v=vs.110).aspx) do `DataTable`

```
foreach(DataRow row in DataTable.Rows)
{         
     int index = DataTable.Rows.IndexOf(row); 
}
```

Porém, o **`DataTable`** sempre vai estar em ordem, então é possível você mesmo controlar o index.

```
int index = 0;
foreach(DataRow row in DataTable.Rows)
{        
     index++;
}
```

Ou então, é possível trocar o `foreach` por um `for` e capturar a `DataRow` pela coleção `Rows` usando o index

```
for(int index = 0; index < DataTable.Rows.Count; index++)
{
    // "index" é o index que você precisa
    var row = DataTable.Rows[index];
}
```